# Fxml file not updating in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm experiencing a weird behaving in **Eclipse** when working with **JavaFx**, when I modify a FXML document in SceneBuilder, I save the changes, but when I run the project, my changes don't appear, it s after I refresh the concerned **Fxml** document that the changes work when I run the application, I'm obliged to do this every time I change something using **SceneBuilder**, any explanation or solution for this problem ?

Comment: I haven't had this problem in netbeans, maybe there is some sort of cache in Eclipse?

Comment: neither have I with Netbeans, but this is what I'm experiencing with eclipse

Comment: Do you open your FXML file with eclipse (right-clic on it "Open with SceneBuilder) or directy by launching SceneBuilder ? In the first case the tomsontom's answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah I'm opening the FXML file by double clicking it (which is same as right click)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Eclipse does NOT by default track external changes to files and when you execute an application you are not executing the stuff in the "src" folder but the one that gets copied by eclipse to your "bin" one.

You can turn on active polling of sources on in the Eclipse Preferences page "General > Workspace" by checking "Refresh using native hooks or polling".

Comment: This default setting is really confusing for a lot of people, it is not self-evident.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a project with option:

"Use project folder as root for sources and class files"

selected, you don't have that problem.